# Why are my values being joined together when getting them from a class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, text-files

I am reading data from a text file and then storing each line in a class, each class is then being stored in an ArrayList.

For example after I have read each line from the text file I store the values in a class.

For Example:

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    line1 = line;                
    line2 = reader.readLine();
    line3 = reader.readLine();
    line4 = reader.readLine();
    line5 = reader.readLine();
    line6 = reader.readLine();
    line7 = reader.readLine();


Person tempPerson = new Person(line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7);
person_list.add(tempPerson);
```

But when I get the values for line6:

```
Person tempPerson = person_list.get(0);
out.print(tempPerson.getLine6());
```

The values that get outputted are merged with line7, for example, 'line7line6'.

All the other lines work perfectly fine apart from when I ask to get line 7 nothing gets returned.

Even when I have try to get details from another 'person' the same issue occurs in the same place.

I have tried new file readers and this hasnt helped, and also when checking on the debugger the values are being stored correctly in the class.

So instead of using an ArrayList I tried to store them in a Array and that didnt seem to help either.

I have been looking to see if there is an issue with my getters and setters and I can't seem to find a problem.

Comment: Are you statically importing `System` and using the `out.print` that way? You want to use `println` if you want to print each value on a seperate line.

Comment: So when you looked at debug in tempPerson all the string objects had correct value ??

Comment: @Mark 'out' is a different class to 'System.out', it displays the output on the JSP page. Also I changed it to 'println' and there was no difference.

Comment: @ygbgames yes that is correct

Comment: In that case if you have override the toString method of person and when you print it on console or so. That is printing all lines as they were red right ??

Comment: @ygbgames It's just when I call it back from the class I run into this problem, it is all being read and stored correctly. I tried overiding the function in the parent class in the sub class and still shows the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your source code:

- you only check for the first line, if it is defined (`(line = reader.readLine()) != null`) => so you don't know if the line exists / has been correctly read
- you use `print`, instead of `println` which would add a line breaker at end

If you provide a source sample, it would be easier to check.

Comment: Does it answer your question?